# Unable to write Redux tests for action creators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, nock

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm following the example for writing tests for async action creators spelled out in the [Redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#async-action-creators]). I'm following the example as closely as possible, but I can't get the test to work. I'm getting the following error message:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
   (node:789) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
   (rejection id: 28): TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

Here is the code for my action creator and test:

actions/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { AUTH_USER, AUTH_ERROR, RESET_AUTH_ERROR } from './types';

const API_HOST = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'
                ? http://production-server
                : 'http://localhost:3090';

export function activateUser(token) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.put(`${API_HOST}/activations/${token}`)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });

        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(authError(error.response.data.error));
      });
  }
}

export function authError(error) {
  return {
    type: AUTH_ERROR,
    payload: error
  }
}
```

confirmation_test.js

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'; 
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from '../../src/actions';
import { AUTH_USER, AUTH_ERROR, RESET_AUTH_ERROR } from 
'../../src/actions/types';
import nock from 'nock';
import { expect } from 'chai';

const middlewares = [ thunk ];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('Confirmation_Token action creator', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    nock.cleanAll()
  });

  it('dispatches AUTH_USER', (done) => {
    nock('http://localhost:3090')
    .put('/activations/123456')
    .reply(200, {
        token: 7891011
    });

    const expectedActions = { type: AUTH_USER };

    const store = mockStore({});

    return store.dispatch(actions.activateUser(123456))
     .then(() => { // return of async actions
       expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
       done();
     });
  });
});
```

**UPDATED QUESTION**

I've partially (though not entirely) figured this out. I got this to work by adding a `return` statement in front of `axios` and commenting out the `localstorage.setItem` call.

I also turned the object I assigned to `expectedActions` to an array, and changed my assertion from `toEqual` to `to.deep.equal`. Here is the modified code:

actions/index.js

```
export function activateUser(token) {
  return function(dispatch) { // added return statement
    return axios.put(`${API_HOST}/activations/${token}`)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
        // localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token); Had to comment out local storage
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(authError(error.response.data.error));
      });
  }
}
```

confirmation_test.js

```
describe('ConfirmationToken action creator', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
     nock.cleanAll()
  });

  it('dispatches AUTH_USER', (done) => {
    nock('http://localhost:3090')
    .put('/activations/123456')
    .reply(200, {
        token: 7891011
     });

    const expectedActions = [{ type: AUTH_USER }];

    const store = mockStore({});

    return store.dispatch(actions.activateUser(123456))
     .then(() => { // return of async actions
       expect(store.getActions()).to.deep.equal(expectedActions);
       done();
     });
   });
 });
```

But now I can't test `localStorage.setItem` without producing this error message:

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called 
in this test.
```

Is this because I need to mock out `localStorage.setItem`? Or is there an easier solve that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. It involves the changes I made in my updated question as well as adding a mock of localStorage to my test_helper.js file. Since there seems to be a lot of questions about this online, I figured perhaps my solution could help someone down the line.

test_helper.js

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';

global.localStorage = storageMock();

global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = global.document.defaultView;
global.navigator = global.window.navigator;

global.window.localStorage = global.localStorage;

// localStorage mock

function storageMock() {
    var storage = {};

    return {
      setItem: function(key, value) {
        storage[key] = value || '';
      },
      getItem: function(key) {
        return key in storage ? storage[key] : null;
      },
      removeItem: function(key) {
        delete storage[key];
      }
    };
  }
```

actions.index.js

```
export function activateUser(token) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return axios.put(`${API_HOST}/activations/${token}`)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(authError(error.response.data.error));
      });
  }
}
```

confirmation_test.js

```
describe('Confirmation action creator', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    nock.cleanAll()
  });

  it('dispatches AUTH_USER and stores token in localStorage', (done) => {
    nock('http://localhost:3090')
    .put('/activations/123456')
    .reply(200, {
        token: '7891011'
    });

    const expectedActions = [{ type: AUTH_USER }];

    const store = mockStore({});

    return store.dispatch(actions.activateUser(123456))
     .then(() => { // return of async actions
       expect(store.getActions()).to.deep.equal(expectedActions);
       expect(localStorage.getItem('token')).to.equal('7891011');
       done();
    });
  });
});
```